# Left Outer Join 2 models and return query in JSON

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF to serialize and have the api endpoints to display json data.

I have 2 models -

```
class FooOne(models.Model):
  field_a = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
  field_b = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
  field_c = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

class FooTwo(models.Model):
  field_fk = models.ForeignKey(FooOne)
  field_d = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
  field_e = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

these are my serializer classes -

```
class FooOneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = FooOne
        fields = (field_a, field_b, field_c)

class FooTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
      field_fk = FooOneSerializer()
      class Meta:
         model = FooTwo
         fields = (field_fk, field_d, field_e)
```

`FooTwoSerializer` will return data with field_fk as a nested dictionary. What i want to is to return other fields of `FooOneSerialzer` that arent foreign key to `FooTwo` and append it the final rendered result of `FooTwoSerializer`.
How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want concatenate the results of `FooOneSerailizer` and all fields of `FooTwoSerializer`. You can do so by overriding `to_represetation()` method.

```
class FooTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

     class Meta:
         model = FooTwo
         fields = (field_d, field_e)

     def to_representation(self, instance):
         # get OrderedDict with original fields
         response = super(FooTwoSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
         # get OrderedDict with foreign foo_one data
         foo_one = FooOneSerializer(instance.field_fk).data
         # set this fields to original data
         for key in foo_one:
             response[key] = foo_one[key]
         return response
```